# Expected Class In C# for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been having tons of issues with this script(I'm new to c#)

```
using UnityEngine; 
public class Death : MonoBehaviour{}
public void Add() //right here I get a "expected class, Delegate, Enum, interface, or struct" error. 

if (isDead) 
{
    DeathCamTag.SetActive(true); 
}
else 
{
    FPSControllerTag.SetActive(true);   
}
```

If I switch it to:

```
using UnityEngine;
public class Death : MonoBehaviour{}{ //namespace dose not directly contain members such as methods
public void Add() //expected class

if (isDead) 
{
    DeathCamTag.SetActive(true); 
}
else 
{
    FPSControllerTag.SetActive(true);   
} 
} //type or namespace def or end of file expected
```

thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before adding them to your question `unity != unity3d`

Comment: This is basic C# syntax, you should start with almost any tutorial on C#. In short all functions have to exist *inside* a class. So those curly braces after your `class` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Should look like this

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Death : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public void Add() //right here I get a "expected class, Delegate, Enum, interface, or struct" error. 
        {
            if (isDead)
            {
                DeathCamTag.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                FPSControllerTag.SetActive(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a namespace, and you're missing a bunch of `{}`. Try:

```
using UnityEngine;

namespace GOTY2015 
{    
    public class Death : MonoBehaviour
    { 
        public void Add() 
        { 
            if (isDead) 
            {
                DeathCamTag.SetActive(true); 
            }
            else 
            {
                FPSControllerTag.SetActive(true);   
            } 
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Technically, he doesn't _need_ a `namespace` (thought he'd better use it anyway).